# compilation error when including jsff file into another one

Tags: java, html, jsp, oracle-adf

I have a project in ADF that have common functionalities such as Last,Next,Rollback and First.

I have many jsff pages that contains the same functionality. So I have added those common functionalities in one jsff page(commonButton.jsff) and want to embed them as an include file where they are used.

So the file with the common functionality is called commonButton.jsff and is shown below with the relevant ids:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<af:button disabled="#{!bindings.Last.enabled  or bindings.Rollback.enabled}" id="b4" partialSubmit="true"
           icon="#{resource['images:Last.png']}" actionListener="#{bindings.Last.execute}"/>
<af:button disabled="#{!bindings.Next.enabled  or bindings.Rollback.enabled}"
           icon="#{resource['images:Forward.png']}" id="b3" partialSubmit="true"
           actionListener="#{bindings.Next.execute}"/>
<af:button disabled="#{!bindings.Previous.enabled  or bindings.Rollback.enabled }"
           icon="#{resource['images:Back.png']}" id="b2" partialSubmit="true"
           actionListener="#{bindings.Previous.execute}"/>
<af:button disabled="#{!bindings.First.enabled  or bindings.Rollback.enabled}"
           icon="#{resource['images:First.png']}" id="b1" partialSubmit="true"
           actionListener="#{bindings.First.execute}"/>
<af:button icon="#{resource['images:Print.png']}" text="#{res.PRINT}" id="b5">
    <af:showPrintablePageBehavior/>
</af:button>
```

I have included the  commonButton.jsff file in the main.jsff as shown below:

```
   <af:toolbar id="tb1">

                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/commonButton.jsff" />

              </af:toolbar>
```

**Note** that commonButton.jsff is found under Web Content folder.

Because I have removed the button from main.jsff to commonButton.jsff I got a compilation error that the following ID does not exist:
**::b4 ::b3 ::b2 ::b1**

the code snippet shown below where the compilation error can be identified:

```
                  <af:table value="#{bindings.module.collectionModel}" var="row"
                                              rows="#{bindings.module.rangeSize}"
                                              emptyText="#{bindings.module.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                                              rowBandingInterval="0"
                                              selectedRowKeys="#{bindings.module.collectionModel.selectedRow}"
                                              selectionListener="#{bindings.module.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                                              rowSelection="single"
                                              fetchSize="#{bindings.module.rangeSize}" id="resId1"
                                              partialTriggers="::b4 ::b3 ::b2 ::b1" scrollPolicy="page">
```

Any idea how I can get the ids in commonButton.jsff to  main.jsff please?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. You have to "think in task flows" when working with ADF. That means, you need to create a bounded task flow including commonButton.jsff. Then drop that task flow inside your page.

But, since you are considering creating a reusable set of buttons across the application, the ideal solution is creating a declarative component:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/24-generic-toolbar-component-169163.pdf